# При компиляции возникает ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат"

Tags: c#

```
double x, y, a = 0;
bool ok; 
ok = false;
x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Входная строка имела неверный формат

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Ввести корректное целочисленное значение в `textBox1`

Comment: Что за `textBox1`? WinForms? Отредактируйте вопрос, укажите, что вводите в указанный текстбокс.

Comment: должны вводится числа, а не текст.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32` выдает это исключение при попытке преобразовать строку неправильного формата. Ожидается строка, представляющая собой целое число, например `"1"` или `"654"`.

Вполне вероятно, что вы не установили значение по умолчанию для своего текстового поля `textBox1`, поэтому оно пытается преобразовать `""` в int, чего не может.

Вы можете решить эту проблему, установив значение по умолчанию или не запуская сравнение, пока значение не будет введено.

Comment: Этот ответ выглядит как ChatGPT, что за `t1`? О каком сравнении чего с чем речь? Значение по умолчанию чего и где?